# Google Play: Publish private app from EMM console gives “Upload a new apk file with a different package name” error

Tags: android, google-play, mdm

I have a private (Enterprise) app in Google Play. It is not in the Public Play Store, only in the Managed Play Store. I have already released it to the company's users through Google Play Console (from where my EMM makes it available to users).

But I am unhappy with the delay I get when I do a release from Google Play Console. So now I want to publish it directly via my EMM (Citrix Xenmobile) using Google's iFrame:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9146439?hl=en

But I get the error:
“Upload a new apk file with a different package name”

It seems that this method tries to create a new app/developer entry instead of using the existing private app information for that package name.

Questions:

1. Is this method really faster than when releasing through Google Play
   Console? Or does the app go through the same processes regardless of
   which method I use?
2. Is it possible to use this method and not having
   to delete/unpublish the app from Google Managed Play?

Answer (score 0):

The play store won't allow a second app with the same `packageName` to be uploaded, an error will be thrown stating that `packageName` already exists

This applies to any google play store, if you uploaded the APP on private play store, you cannot upload it on the public play store and vice versa.

And as for the time it takes it's usually the same across platform, updates on the other hand are published really quick.

Comment: OK. The app is not in the public play store, I have checked.

Comment: Yes, because you did not upload it to public playstore. It was uploaded to private playstore